# Why can't composer find package laravel/homestead at any version for minimum-stability stable?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am setting up homestead.

I have installed the vagrant box, cloned the homestead repo, and initialized homestead.

I want to install homestead to this project as a "per project" install.

I cd into my project directory, and run

```
composer require laravel/homestead --dev
```

I get the error:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package laravel/homestead at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

What's going on? Why should I have to set minimum stability to dev on the project to get homestead working? Is there not a stable version of homestead?

Comment: also having this issue

Comment: @djt Try installing again today. I don't know if there were issues with the rep or what, but it's working now.